# Append element with jQuery in sync with CSS transition delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to be able to append a relatively positioned element in my menu to the absolutely positioned dropdown menu. This is fine to do with jQuery - however, there's a CSS transition delay on the dropdown menu, and I'm having difficulty working out a clean way to handle the append so that it's in sync with the dropdown menu becoming active.

The top level menu has a 500ms transition delay before the dropdown will become active. I need to make sure the jQuery append of the "block" element works in sync with this. Does anyone have any guidance for a good way to handle this? I don't have flexibility to rework the markup.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.main-menu > li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).addClass('active');

      $('.block').appendTo($(this).find('.dropdown'));

    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');

      $('.block').appendTo('.header');
    }
  })

});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: yellow;
}

.dropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 200ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 20;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

li.active .dropdown {
  transition: all 0s linear 500ms;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.block {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu-subcategory">
              <h4><a href="/sub">Sub Cat</a></h4>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu-subcategory">
              <h4><a href="/sub">Sub Cat</a></h4>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu-subcategory">
              <h4><a href="/sub">Sub Cat</a></h4>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="block">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
        dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas
        at lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: if it's the same block why are you removing that from the header and attaching it to li? can't it be present in both 'header' and 'li'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to remove the .block from .header and add it to li and remove it again. If it needs to be always present. My guess is you are looking for clone.

See if the below snippet solve your purpose

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $('.block').clone().appendTo($('li').find('.dropdown'));
 $('.main-menu > li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  })
 

});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: yellow;
}

.dropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 200ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 20;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

li.active .dropdown {
  transition: all 0s linear 500ms;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.block {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu-subcategory">
              <h4><a href="/sub">Sub Cat</a></h4>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu-subcategory">
              <h4><a href="/sub">Sub Cat</a></h4>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu-subcategory">
              <h4><a href="/sub">Sub Cat</a></h4>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 5</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 6</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 7</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/test">Test 8</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="block">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
        dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas
        at lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec gravida est mauris, nec blandit dui elementum vitae. Pellentesque aliquet magna vel lorem porta, nec scelerisque augue volutpat. Mauris sed eros a erat bibendum venenatis vulputate nec
      dui. Maecenas tristique at leo et finibus. Maecenas euismod volutpat tortor, non aliquet arcu commodo quis. Aliquam mollis condimentum orci at efficitur. Fusce turpis sapien, ornare ac tincidunt sed, consectetur sit amet purus. Vivamus egestas at
      lorem non hendrerit.</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution - I'll test it shortly and accept. I guess I was trying to avoid duplicating the element in each dropdown but there's no issue with this that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

How about use the 'transitionend' or 'animationend' event like this:
obj.addEventListener('transitionend', doSomething );
obj.addEventListener('animationend', doSomething );
also you can use 'webkitTransitionEnd' and 'webkitAnimationEnd' in Chrome, Safari and Opera.